# How to declare entity for DocumentDbRepositories as per the geospatial json

Tags: spring-boot, geospatial, azure-cosmosdb

I just need to get this same response for my Spring boot rest API

The below GeoSpatial JSON

```
 {
    "id": "dfasdfsfrwrwr",
    "name": "sample name",
    "address": "sample adress",
    "area": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [ [
              [ -73.9580, 40.8003 ],
              [ -73.9498, 40.7968 ],
              [ -73.9737, 40.7648 ],
              [ -73.9814, 40.7681 ],
              [ -73.9580, 40.8003 ]
        ] ]
    }
}
```